# How to ignore Robocopy access denied errors in psake?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, robocopy, psake

I am writing psake task for copying a folder to another folder as below.

```
task -name CopyComponentToBundle -description "Copy the component to bundle" -action {

    Write "Component source is $ComponentPath"
    Write "Component Destination is $ComponentBundlePath"
    exec {      

        Robocopy $ComponentPath $ComponentBundlePath  /MIR /R:0 /W:0
    }   
}
```

though folders are successfully copied still i am getting error as below.

> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\psake\psake.psm1:156
>   char:17 +                 throw ("Exec: " + $errorMe ssage) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Exception: Exec: Error
>   executing command
>                                   Roboc opy $ComponentPath $ComponentBundlePath  /MIR /R:0 /W:0 .

Is there a way to ignore the errors? All the errors were "Access is denied".

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding this right before the robocopy command

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```